# Import data table from database into QGIS using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, database

I need to import a data table from a database into QGIS using PyQGIS. This table is not QgsVectorLayer and there is not any geometry. That is probably why this is not working. How can I do it?

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("IP_addr", "5432", "gis", "user", "pass")
uri.setDataSource("public", "typy_vykopu", "", "")
table = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "typy_vykopu_stazene", "postgres")
if not table.isValid():
    print "Table %s did not load" % table.name()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([table])
```

Comment: What does `table.isValid()` return?

Comment: Thank you for reaction. I just solve my problem. Now I am using psycopg2 for connect to database.

Comment: well, I posted the solution as anyway ;)

Comment: it would be "nice" to indicate whether oscar's answer was THE answer to your question ... you apparently want to import a postgis table ... but what does your _"This table is not QgsVectorLayer"_ mean ?... are you talking about your **table** variable ? meaning there is something wrong with your connection to the database ... ?

Comment: @snaileater I guess he was importing data in QGIS a simple Postgresql table without geometry. This could be done with pyqgis using the answer below.... Table variable obviusly **is** a QgsVectorLayer object....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set **None** instead '' for geometry column:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("IP_addr", "5432", "gis", "user", "pass")
uri.setDataSource("public", "typy_vykopu", None, "")
table = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "typy_vykopu_stazene", "postgres")
if not table.isValid():
    print "Table %s did not load" % table.name()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([table])
```

Comment: Ou... this is classic. My problem would be solved by one word. Thank you very much Oscar!

Comment: As snaileater pointed take care that `table` variable obviusly is a _QgsVectorLayer_ object, but without geometry.

Comment: `QgsMapLayerRegistry`  has been removed and its functionality has been moved to `QgsProject`, so the last line should be:
`QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(table)`